# What is the difference between 'Make' and 'Gradle-aware Make'?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I saw in my Run/Debug Configurations that before launch there would a call to 'Make' first then 'Gradle-aware Make'. When I created a new project and checked its config I saw that there was only 'Gradle-aware Make' in it. I was wondering whether on my previous project I could take out 'Make' since it doubles my compile time. I did already take it out though and found no complications.

[image: Project with Make and Gradle-aware Make]

[image: Newly created Project with default settings]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually documented [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig.html):

Make

> Compile the project or the module. Android Studio executes the Make Module command if the run/debug configuration specifies a particular module, or it executes the Make Project command if no modules are specified.

Gradle-aware make

> Compile the project and run Gradle.

You can remove Make, it is not enabled for new projects so it's not necessary.